# Extract field from nested JSON object

Tags: tabulator

I have a JSON result set that contains nested JSON objects in each row.  Is there a way to define a column in the table as "object.field"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do exactly that. Say that your row data looks like this:

```js
{
    id:1,
    user:{
        name:"steve",
        age:23
    },
    col:"red",
    cheese:true
}
```

If you wanted to setup a column so that it looks at the name property of the user object you can set the field to `user.name`

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"user.name"},  //link column to name property of user object
    ],
});
```

Checkout the [Nested Data Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/columns#field-nesting) for more info.